# How can I modify the code to drag multiple QPushButtons

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to implement multiple Push Buttons, all of them having the ability to be drag/drop, the issue only one button can be drag and drop

I tried to create functions for each button, this is my code:

```
class DigitalBoard(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DigitalBoard, self).__init__()
        
        loadUi("DigitalBoardMain.ui",self)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

#For button 1:
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton
            mimeData = QMimeData()
            drag = QDrag(self)
            drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
        
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        position = event.pos()
        self.A_1btn.move(position)
        event.accept()

#For button2 
    def mouseMoveEvent1(self, event):
            event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton
            mimeData = QMimeData()
            drag = QDrag(self)
            drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
            drag.exec_(Qt.MoveAction)
        
    def dragEnterEvent1(self, event1):
        event1.accept()
    def dropEvent1(self, event):
        position1 = event.pos()
        self.A2.move(position1)
        event1.accept()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time to follow the [tour] and read [ask], and consider that we normally answer to specific and detailed questions. We don't provide tutorials or solutions to questions like "I'd like to know how to do xyz". I'm sorry, but your question is too broad, and we cannot answer with vague requirements. For instance, do you want to be able to move all buttons, or just some? What contains those buttons? How can "movable" buttons be distinguished from others that shouldn't be moved? If only some buttons can be moved, how are they "selected"?

Comment: Also, the code you're providing is quite unclear: 1. the syntax is wrong and unreadable (please check about proper ways to [format code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362)); 2. it's unclear to what classes those "For button 1" and "For button 2" belong. Please take your time to revise your question, ensure you clarify your needs in a **precise** way, and provide a valid [mre].